# blazor - save form with related entities

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm trying to save a form that contains related entity. My activityRequest.CustomerActivity is null, when OnInitialized is called, so the render bugs with null exception. I don't even get why it's trying to oninitialized before going to save, but i also don't understand why the related entity is null

```
@page "/ActivityRequests/edit"
@using Labyrinthe.Data
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

<PageTitle>Nouvelle demande</PageTitle>
<PageTitle>Edit</PageTitle>
<a href="/customers">Retour à la liste</a>
<hr />
@if(ActivityRequest != null)
@if(ActivityRequest.ID>0)
{
    <h1>@ActivityRequest.RequestNumber @ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Activity.Name</h1>
}

                @if (CustomerActivityID != 0)
                {
    <h1>Nouvelle demande</h1>

                }

<hr />
@if (ActivityRequest is null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <EditForm method="post" Model="ActivityRequest" OnSubmit="UpdateActivityRequest" FormName="edit" Enhance>
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">

                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="col">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Nom" class="form-label">Nom:</label>
                                <InputText id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Name" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Name" class="form-control" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Name" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Nom" class="form-label">Téléphone:</label>
                                <InputText id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Phone" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Phone" class="form-control" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Phone" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>

                           <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Nom" class="form-label">Note:</label>
                                <InputTextArea id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Note" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Note" class="form-control" [rows]="1" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.Note" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                            <h3>Contact</h3>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Nom" class="form-label">Nom:</label>
                                        <InputText id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Contact.Name" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Contact.Name" class="form-control" />
                                        <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Contact.Name" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Phone" class="form-label">Téléphone:</label>
                                        <InputText id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Contact.Phone" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Contact.Phone" class="form-control" />
                                        <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Contact.Phone" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Adresse de rue" class="form-label">Adresse de facturation:</label>
                                <InputText id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress" class="form-control" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.StreetAddress" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Ville" class="form-label">Ville:</label>
                                <InputSelect id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.City" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.CityID" class="form-control">
                                    @if (scheduleBlocks != null)
                                        @foreach (var city in Cities)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@city.ID">@city.Name</option>
                                        }
                                </InputSelect>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.CityID" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="Province" class="form-label">Province:</label>
                                <InputSelect id="ActivityRequest.ScheduleBlockID" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.TerritoryID" class="form-control">
                                    @if (scheduleBlocks != null)
                                        @foreach (var territory in Territories)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@territory.ID">@territory.Name</option>
                                        }
                                </InputSelect>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.CityID" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label for="Code postal" class="form-label">Code postal:</label>
                                        <InputText id="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode" class="form-control" />
                                        <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress.PostalCode" class="text-danger" />
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <InputCheckbox id="SameAddress" @bind-Value="SameAddress" @bind:after="OnSameAddressChanged"/>

                                            <label for="SameAddress" class="form-label">Adresse d'activité</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                            </div>

                            </div>
                            </div>                         
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="" class="form-label">Mode de contact: </label>
                                <InputSelect id="ContactMode" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.ContactModeID" class="form-control">
                                    @if (ContactModes != null)
                                        @foreach (var contactMode in ContactModes)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@contactMode.ID">@contactMode.Name</option>
                                        }
                                </InputSelect>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.ContactModeID" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
 
                       
                        </div>

                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ActivityRequest.ID" value="@ActivityRequest.ID" />
                            <InputNumber hidden id="CustomerActivityID" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.CustomerActivityID" class="form-control" />
                            
                            
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="description" class="form-label">Description:</label>
                                <InputTextArea id="description" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.Description" class="form-control" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.Description" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="" class="form-label">Période: </label>
                                <InputSelect id="ActivityRequest.ScheduleBlockID" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.ScheduleBlockID" class="form-control">
                                    @if (scheduleBlocks != null)
                                        @foreach (var schedule in scheduleBlocks)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@schedule.ID">@schedule.Name</option>
                                        }
                                </InputSelect>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.ScheduleBlockID" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="startdate" class="form-label">Date et heure de début:</label>
                                <InputDate id="startdate" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.StartDate" @bind-Value:format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" Type="InputDateType.DateTimeLocal" class="form-control" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.StartDate" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="hourtime" class="form-label">Temps (heures):</label>
                                <InputNumber id="hourtime" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.HourTime" class="form-control" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.HourTime" class="text-danger" />
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="col">

                            <label for="participantsnumber" class="form-label">Participants:</label>
                            <InputNumber id="participantsnumber" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.ParticipantsNumber" class="form-control" />
                            <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.ParticipantsNumber" class="text-danger" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="sessionsnumber" class="form-label">Session:</label>
                            <InputNumber id="sessionsnumber" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.SessionsNumber" class="form-control" />
                            <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.SessionsNumber" class="text-danger" />

                        </div>



                            </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="interactiveframe" class="form-label">Tableau interactif:</label>
                        <InputCheckbox id="interactiveframe" @bind-Value="ActivityRequest.InteractiveFrame" class="form-check-input" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="() => ActivityRequest.InteractiveFrame" class="text-danger" />
                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


    </EditForm>
}

<div>
    <a href="/activityrequests">Back to List</a>
</div>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public int CustomerActivityID { get; set; }
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public bool SameAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public List<Territory> Territories { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduleBlock> scheduleBlocks { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public List<ContactMode> ContactModes { get; set; }
    [Inject] IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> Factory { get; set; }
    ApplicationDbContext db;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public ActivityRequest? ActivityRequest { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        db = Factory.CreateDbContext();

        Customers = await db.Customers.Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted).ToListAsync();
        scheduleBlocks = await db.ScheduleBlocks.Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted).ToListAsync();
        Addresses = await db.Addresses.Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted)
        .Include(a => a.City)
        .Include(a => a.Country)
        .Include(a => a.Territory)
        .ToListAsync();
        Contacts = await db.Contacts.Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted).ToListAsync();
        ContactModes = await db.ContactModes.Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted).ToListAsync();
        Cities = await db.Cities.Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted).ToListAsync();
        Territories = await db.Territories.Where(c => c.Status != Status.Deleted).ToListAsync();
        if (ActivityRequest == null)
            if (ID == 0)
            {
                ActivityRequest = new ActivityRequest();

                if (CustomerActivityID != 0)
                {
                    CustomerActivity customerActivity = db.CustomerActivities.Where(ca => ca.ID == CustomerActivityID)
                    .Include(ca => ca.Activity)
                    .Include(ca => ca.Customer)
                    .Include(ca => ca.Address)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Country)
                    .Include(ca => ca.Address)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Country)
                    .Include(ca => ca.Address)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Territory)

                    .Include(ca => ca.Contact)
                .First();
                    ActivityRequest.StartDate = (DateTime)customerActivity?.Activity.DateTimeRequest;
                    ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity = customerActivity;
                    ActivityRequest.CustomerActivityID = customerActivity.ID;
                    //ActivityRequest.ScheduleBlockID = db.ScheduleBlocks.First().ID;

                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day+1, 9, 0, 0);

                    ActivityRequest.StartDate = date;

                    if(CustomerID == 0)
                    {
                        CustomerActivity customerActivity = new CustomerActivity();
                        customerActivity.Customer = new Customer();
                        //customerActivity.Address = new Address();
                        ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity = customerActivity;
                        ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress = new Address();
                        SameAddress = true;
                        customerActivity.Address = ActivityRequest.CustomerActivity.Customer.BillingAddress;
                        customerActivity.Contact = new Contact();

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        CustomerActivity customerActivity = new CustomerActivity();

                        customerActivity.Customer = Customers.First(c => c.ID == CustomerID);
                        Addresses = await db.Addresses.Where(a => a.CustomerAddresses.Where(ca => ca.CustomerID == CustomerID).Count()>0).ToListAsync();

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityRequest ??= await db.ActivityRequests
                .Include(ar => ar.CustomerActivity)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Customer)
                .Include(ar => ar.CustomerActivity)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Activity)
                .Include(ar => ar.CustomerActivity)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Contact)
                .Include(ar => ar.CustomerActivity)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Address)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.TerritoryID)
                .Include(ar => ar.CustomerActivity)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Address)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.City)
                .Include(ar => ar.CustomerActivity)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Address)
                .ThenInclude(ca => ca.Country)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == ID);

                if (ActivityRequest is null)
                {
                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("notfound");
                }

            }
    }

    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    public async Task UpdateActivityRequest()
    {
        if (ActivityRequest.ID == 0)
        {
            db.Attach(ActivityRequest!).State = EntityState.Added;
            ActivityRequest.Status = Status.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            db.Attach(ActivityRequest!).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ActivityRequest.Status = Status.Modified;
        }


        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/activityrequests");
    }

    bool ActivityRequestExists(int id)
    {
        return db.ActivityRequests.Any(e => e.ID == id);
    }
    void OnSameAddressChanged()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I removed the related entity part and it calls the update, the rendering doesn't bug

Comment: Do you understand the [Blazor Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0)?

Comment: @Marius definitely not enough. I'm fine with the start but i don't understand what is going on after that. why is rendering happening again before post function